# Neural network for colored line detection?

Tags: neural-network, detection

Can I use a Neural Network to find at least 3 pixels (that have RGB or HSV values in a certain range) in a line?
I would like to teach the network to accept when and when not accept the line, is possible to do such thing?
The lines are scanned by a scanner, when the network goes looking for some colored lines I first look at the paper with the real picture and then tell the network whether it should accept or not.

Comment: I always found the hard part of writing neural network software to be the feature extraction necessary before sending massaged data to the net. I'd suggest trying to figure out how you can find the important pixels, their locations, their colors, and so forth, in some procedural code before trying to send the mess of data to the network. (You might find you don't need the neural net at all, which would be a shame if it's a homework project...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it would be suboptimal.

Assuming you're only looking at a straight line(and not a full 2-dimensional page), you would have to call the neural network for every group of 3 adjacent pixels on the line(i.e. O(N) times).
And even then the task would be simple enough for you to program the solution directly.

A neural network is good at classifying things, not so much at finding things.
I.e. a good use for an NN would be to recognize handwritten letters on a line. A bad use for it would be to recognize where a line is on a page.